Instructions about opcua commander on certificates
I am currently creating an opcua server with the open62541 lib in C.
and I recently implemented a certificate management and a SecurityPolicy(basic256sha256) on the server side. As a client, I am using the open-source program opcua commander, however I have
troubles using it correctly.
To some extent, I even could connect to the server, but I think that I dont correctly integrated
a certificate via a parameter in the command. I call the opcua commander with this command:
node dist/index.js -e opc.tcp://localhost:4840 -P=Basic256Sha256 -s SignAndEncrypt
So I know that there is an explicit directory for certs used by the commander(.config/opcua-commander-nodejs/pki/own/certs/...), however I dont know, how to add the cert to the program, if it isnt already. On the server side I built up on the examples given in the open62541 lib, and just give the opcua commander .pem as the last parameter for the trust list
(args: <server-certificate.der> <private-key.der> [<trustlist1.crl>, ...]).
So to conclude, my question is: how can I correctly implement the certificate? Is there any documentation available for the commander? Do I have to change something on my server code to correctly pass the .pem cert? Is it even the right cert?
Im happy if anyone can help me. And thanks for any comment in Advance.
Copying the opcua_commander_certificate.pem and passing it as the last argument to my server call.
